# MySQL Error with /index.php?=page but not on memberlist.php

Tags: php, mysql

When I added php pagination and go to this link /index.php?page=memberlist I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a4398909/public_html/memberlist.php on line 312
```

But when I  go to memberlist.php it works fine. So i don't know what's wrong, here is my code:

```
        <?php
/*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
    // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="users";      //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "/index.php?page=memberlist";     //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$prev\">� previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page_num=$next\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
} ?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>

         <div style="float: left; width: 300px; margin-left: 11px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius:7px; background-color:#666;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
<div id="memberlist_top">
    <div id="memberlist_avatar">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['avatar'] ?>" style="border: 1px solid #CBCBCB; padding: 3px; width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="memberlist_top_right">
        <p id="memberlist_username"><a href="/index.php?page=user&id=<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></a></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="<?php echo$row['site_rank_image']?>"</p>
        <p style="text-align: center;" id="ml_rep"> Reputation: 0 </p>
        <p id="ml_posts">Post count: <?php echo $row['post'] ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="memberlist_bottom">
    <p id="ml_bottom_p"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> Date Registered: <span id="ml_bottom_span"><?php echo date(" F j, Y, g:i A", strtotime($row['user_date']))?> </span></p>
    <p id="ml_bottom_p"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> Last online: <span id="ml_bottom_span"><?php echo date(" F j, Y, g:i A", strtotime($row['dt']))?> </span></p>
    <p id="ml_bottom_p" style="width: 284px; height: 30px; overflow-x: hidden; cursor: pointer;" title="Coming Soon"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> Last Activity: <span id="ml_bottom_span" style="text-decoration: underline;">Coming Soon</span></p>
    <p id="ml_bottom_p"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> Is online now: <span id="ml_bottom_span"> <? if($row

['online'] == 1) {  // checks to see if the user allows their email to be shown, where '1' means they allow it to be shown
echo'Yes';
} else { echo'No'; // if they allow it, it displays their email } ?> </span></p>
</div>
```

```
    <? }
?>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong, because I can't find it. I'm new to php.

I got this code from http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Comment: Is this the whole source code. Your error says you have error on line 312, but your code has only 150 lines =)

Comment: I only added the php code part.

Comment: Try adding `echo mysql_error();` After each `mysql_query` To display exactly what the SQL error is. Maybe you don't have the uses table or something else ;)

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: @DoSparKot Where do I add it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your query.   Try changing your query line to:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Comment: Please don't provide solutions with deprecated APIs.

Comment: I get Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-2, 2' at line 1

Comment: Your pagination algorithm is clearly wrong - you can't have a negative value in the LIMIT clause.

Comment: @DoSparKot - While I agree that the OP should be using the updated libs, items are deprecated for several years before being removed because there are often projects that are so large and cumbersome that it is not feasible to update deprecated code overnight.  Therefore, sometimes a coder has no choice but to use deprecated items.

Comment: You are getting that error because the value of $start is -2.  Your code causes $start to get a value of -2 if $page is set to 0.  Move the if ($page == 0) $page = 1; line to above your query call.